# How to resolve system cannot find the path specified error in windows 10 Java?

Tags: java, path, system

I am brand new at Java and have been trying to write "Hello World!". I have gotten far enough to install java with jdk and I've see countless videos on the environmental variables and setting those up with the paths. In the CMD when I write Java or Javac, it works fine, but trying to do step #4 (compiling) on this step by step site: http://www.codejava.net/java-core/how-to-write-compile-and-run-a-hello-world-java-program-for-beginners
I get completely stuck. Its when I am trying to "change the directory" that it tells me that the system cannot find the path.. Right now I'm at a complete loss.

Any suggestions on what I need to do? I am  happy to post screen shots if that will assist as well.

*Java error picture:*

[image: java error pic here]

Comment: You need to be in the directory where you saved your java file. In the tutorial, that's "C:\Java", but you must have saved it elsewhere.

Comment: Best I've got, because you could totally be correct. Is that my Java files are saved C:\Program Files\Java. Thats where Java is saved and the file that I am trying to run. So I must change something to get it to reference there, right?

Comment: Then you need to type `cd "C:\Program Files\Java"` instead of `cd C:\Java`.

Comment: Thank you - yes I was able to do that and I was able to successfully compile the program, and I saw in the directory the completion of a .class file, so then I went to run the program and I got "Error: could not find or load main class HelloWorld"

I had C:\Program Files\Java>java HelloWorld 

And thats what the error was.. So I'm puzzled how I can compile it and everything, but the last step of running it does not go through.. thoughts?

Comment: Scratch that - I got it!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When running the command in the prompt window, Windows is looking at the `PATH` environment variable.
Make sure that the `bin` directory of the JDK is referenced in that variable.

Comment: Hi Simon,

Yes thank you - I double checked that and in my 'path' I have ';%JAVE_HOME%\bin;', is that what you were speaking of? I checked probably 10 different sites/youtube videos and that seemed to be what I was supposed to do.. What do you think? Thank you!

Comment: What if in the prompt window, you `set path="C:\[complete_path]\bin"` first ?

Comment: Like this: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin ? Because that is how I have had it and I seem to of made it past the path error, but truthfully I dont know how I did.. Above I ran into a problem of not being able to load a main class, but I am trying to figure that out now..Thanks!